# Unable to go build with private vendor dependency

Tags: go, github, github-actions

So I am unable to `go build` a project in Docker on GitHub Actions.
What i'm doing currently;

1. `vendor/` is not checked into git per best practices
2. Access to private github repos is setup with `git config --global url."https://${USER}:${TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"`
3. Modules are downloaded with `GOPRIVATE="github.com/company" go mod download`
4. A build is triggered via docker which does a `COPY . /go/src/app` and `CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -mod=readonly -ldflags '-w -s -extldflags "-static"'`

However the last build step always fails with: `go: github.com/company/project@v1.0.1: reading github.com/company/project/go.mod at revision v1.0.1: unknown revision v1.0.1`

The tag/release does exist on github since:

```
% git ls-remote --tags
From github.com:company/project
4fda886537a6319bd03ece01277cbc567b97b886    refs/tags/v1.0.0
4fda886537a6319bd03ece01277cbc567b97b886    refs/tags/v1.0.1
```

Any ideas why `go build` with `-mod=readonly` wouldn't work on Docker in GitHub Actions? The only difference I can see is that locally I checkout over SSH instead of HTTPS.

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but you could try fetching all history for tags and branches. See [here](https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches)

Comment: @peterevans: not sure what you mean, but the issue is on the other private git repo which is fetched with `go mod download`, not on the current repo which uses `checkout`.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood.